# Is there a symbol for what a logic gate yields?

Tags: symbolic-logic, propositional-logic

Is there a logic symbol for what output a logic gate yields?

For instance, for an AND gate:

| A | B | A ^ B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T | T | T |
| T | F | F |
| F | T | F |
| F | F | F |

I want to propagate A ^ B into output C, but I wouldn't want to use `A ^ B → C` because implication has a different truth table. Is `A ^ B = C` really the best option?

Comment: [Symbol for assignment of a truth-value?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2603979/152568)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you mean that C is the same as A ∧ B, you can say C = A ∧ B.  C ⇔ A ∧ B is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really clear what you are trying to do. Simply writing A ^ B already expresses what the conjunction of A with B yields.

A ^ B = C is not a well-formed formula in predicate logic. = is conventionally used as the identity predicate and cannot stand between propositions.

You are perhaps trying to express what goes on in a programming language when a value is assigned to a variable. In which case, different languages use different symbols, such as

```
   =    :=    <-    <<
```

Comment: It's competely valid to use equality "=" between logical propositions.  See here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equality It means the same thing as "⇔".